# is it possible to select/open/show a specific addon tab from script?

Tags: python, interface, add-on, select

I want to select and open in the 3D View sidebar a specific addon tab, but I'm not finding any clue in the docs.

I managed to open the sidebar with:
`space.show_region_ui = True`
but I don't know how to get addons tab list and select which one to show.

[image]

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: I realize that this is not what you're asking for. But, if there is a way to do what you want, wouldn't it only work on a new Blender file? Whatever is saved after that will be saved in that state with whatever tab was open at that time. If you want this particular tab to be open every time you start a new project, just select the tab and then save this as your startup file.

Comment: @curious_1 indeed, but I'm working on a script to setup the UI for a specific workflow, splitting and arranging window areas. In one of the areas I wanto to show a specific addon tab open when I run the script (operator), no need to save that state.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I can't help. Unless someone comes along with an answer here, you might try asking this question on the Blender Artists forum: https://blenderartists.org/ If you do, I suggest adding the additional details about what you want to do that you put in your comment.